# Comparing element order in Python lists

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that returns `True` if the elements in `lst1` appear in `lst2` in the same order as they appear in `lst1`, but not necessarily consecutively.

For example,

`test([29, 5, 100], [20, 29, 30, 50, 5, 100])` should return `True`.

`test([25, 65, 40], [40, 25, 30, 65, 1, 100])` should return `False`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def test(lst1, lst2):
    for i in range(len(lst1)-len(lst2)+1):
        if lst2 == lst1[i:i+len(lst2)]:
            return True 
    return False
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is an iterative version of the method using `index` given by Triptych. I think this is probably the best way to do this, as `index` should be faster than any manual indexing or iteration:

```
def test(lst1, lst2):
    start = 0
    try:
        for item in lst1:
            start = lst2.index(item, start) + 1
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True
```

It should perform much better in Python than a recursive version. It also correctly adds one to the start point after each search so as not to give false positives when there are duplicates in the first list.

Here are two solutions that iterate primarily over `lst2` instead of `lst1`, but are otherwise similar to jedwards' version.

The first is straightforward, and uses indexing, but only indexes when you actually move to a different item in `lst1`, rather than for every item in `lst2`:

```
def test(lst1, lst2):
    length, i, item = len(lst1), 0, lst1[0]
    for x in lst2:
        if x == item:
            i += 1
            if i == length:
                return True
            item = lst1[i]
    return False
```

The second uses manual iteration over `lst1` with `next` rather than indexing:

```
def test(lst1, lst2):
    it = iter(lst1)
    try:
        i = next(it)
        for x in lst2:
            if x == i:
                i = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        return True
    return False
```

Both are probably slight improvements as they do less indexing and have no need to construct a `range` for every item in `lst1`.

Comment: This is a really well-developed answer -- always interesting to see different approaches to the same problem, since its easy (at least for me) to get caught up in your initial solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Recursively, no clobbered lists, no new sublists, failing early**

```
def find_all(needle, haystack, npos=0, hpos=0):
  if npos >= len(needle):
    return True
  try:
    return find_all(needle, haystack, npos+1, haystack.index(needle[npos], hpos)+1) 
  except ValueError:
    return False


print find_all([1,3,5], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]) # True
print find_all([1,5,3], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]) # False
```

Comment: Though do note that while this is side-effect free and efficient in the average case, very large needles will run into Python's stack frame limit.

Comment: It's trivial to rewrite this to be iterative instead of recursive, which fits Python's style (and performance characteristics -- high function call overhead) better. See my answer. Also, you neglected to add 1 to `hpos` in the recursive call -- you will get false positives with repeated values in the needle but not the haystack.

Comment: @agf - just trying to point the answers in the right direction :) Thanks for the expanded answer.

Comment: Yep, the concept is definitely good. Didn't mean my comment to sound negative :)

Comment: I did try to warn people not to actually do it this way. I'm just very into recursion and pure functional programming these days...

Answer (score 1):

This scans the lists and is a different approach:

```
def test(lst1, lst2):
    p2 = 0
    length = len(lst2)
    for e1 in lst1:
        for p in range(p2, length):
            if e1 == lst2[p]:
                p2 = p
                break
        else:
            return False    
    return True
```

For each element in `lst1` it searches the subset of list 2 (between `p2` and the end) for it.  If it is found, it restricts the range following searches by updating `p2`.  If it is not found, `False` is returned.  `True` is returned if every element in `lst1` is found.

Comment: You should use the else clause on the inner loop instead of `element_found`, and only call `len` once outside the loops. I've edited your answer to show this. I've also posted two different takes on this method in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
def test(lst1, lst2):
    for x in lst2:
        if x == lst1[0]:
            del lst1[0]
    return lst1 == []
```

Should work.

Comment: `del lst1[0]` is O(n) so this is inefficient.